# clear click queue from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue

I have a click event that triggers other click events that adds an element to the DOM. 
EDIT: But when I click it a second time two elements get added and third time two elements get added. When I check the jQuery queue it confirms that I have added an event to the queue that fires every time.

What I try to accomplish is to add a click event to two dropdownlists by clicking another element.

```
$(".step-1 a").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var userValue = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".template-image").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).children(":first").addClass("selected");
        $("#page_template option ").each(function(){
            var t = $(this);
            var cValue = t.attr("value");

            if(t.attr("selected") === "selected"){
                t.removeAttr("selected");
            }
            if(t.attr("value") === userValue ){
                t.prop("selected", "selected");
                $('#page_template').trigger('change');
                var template = t.attr("value");
                switch (template)
                {
                case "default":
                  $(".step-2").slideDown("fast");
                  $(".step-2").addClass("show");
                  break;
                default:
                  $(".step-2").removeClass("show");
                  $(".step-2").slideUp("fast");
                  break;
                }
            }
        });
    });

$('.step-2 img').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var userinput = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.flexible-footer .acf-fc-add').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
        if(text === "Add columns"){
            $(this).trigger('click');
            $('.flexible-footer .acf-fc-popup ul li a').each(function(){
                var column = $(this).attr('data-layout');
                if (column === userinput) {
                    $(this).trigger('click');
                    $(this).finish();
                    console.log($(this).queue());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're assigning click events multiple times on the same elements. A simple solution to this problem is to use the jQuery function [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the old click-event before adding a new one. Or make sure you're only adding the click event to new element that doesn't already have them. You can do it like this:

```
$('img.or-whatever').off('click').on('click', function(ev){...});
```

Or maybe use namespaces for increased readability:

```
$('img.or-whatever').off('click.custom-namespace').on('click.custom-namespace', function(ev){...});
```

It might not be the correct answer to your question, but it might be a solution.

Edit:
If you just want to clear the event queue, you could try [clearQueue()](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/).

Comment: I tried this and it seems to stop the click event from happening again if I add .off(). I also noticed that the first click fires one click event and the second click will fire two click events and that it will stay with two clicks for very click.

Comment: If you want to just clear the event queue on the first run, maybe you could try http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/ ?

Comment: Thank's for the tip. I tried that but didn't get it to work, but I am going to try again and see if I can find a way to make it work.